# intl-tel-input give a "Real" telephone number

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Right now, I'm using this plugin

https://intl-tel-input.com/

For international telephone field. But when I used one of their function like `$("#vender_tel").intlTelInput("getNumber")` to get the number that country code+user inputed phone number, it's ripped all symbol from user inputed phone number

For example, if I insert phone number to be `SG(+65) 123-123`, it will return value `+65123123` not `+65123-123`.

Is there's any solution for this ? or is there's any alternative plugin for this task that can do that ?

Comment: Don't know the plugin but it makes sense that it returns a normalised value for the sake of consistency.  If you want to apply formatting why not reformat the returned value?

Comment: actually, there's no fixed format (ex: 3 number and then "-" then continue with the number and so on) too. so how can I reformat if I don't have the rules @AlexK. ?? :/